# If periodic function without lowest positive period is continuous then it is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, periodic-functions

I am beginner at real analysis so I am doubtfull on my proof technices. Please check my proof.

Proposition: Suppose that $f$ is periodic, continuous, and that there exists no lowest positive
period. Show that $f$ is constant.

My proof: By definition continiuty we have  $ \vert x-0 \vert \ < \delta   \Rightarrow \vert f(x)-f(0)\vert < \varepsilon $

And we know that if there is no lowest period then every open interval contains a period (however this interval is small).

Consider an increasing sequence $\delta_k < \delta$

Choose $y_k$ and a period $t_k$ from the interval $(-\frac {\delta_k}{2}, \frac {\delta_k}{2})$.

Hence $\vert f(y_k+t_k)-f(0)\vert=\vert f(y_k+nt_k)-f(0)\vert < \varepsilon$

By this way we know that as $y_k, t_k$ can be arbitary small and n ranges over integers we can obtain all domain of the function.

Comment: I think I have to require $  x+t  \in \left] a-\delta, a+\delta \right[  $ ???

Comment: How do you deduce from this that $f$ is constant?

Comment: because  n ranges over the integers. hmm it seems I had to choose period arbitary small????

Comment: @Bungo I guess I was wrong I thought with nt I can obtain all domain...

Comment: @Bungo I made changes can you look up again???

Answer (score 1):

By hypothesis, there exists a sequence $p_n$ such that $f(x+p_n) = f(x)$ for all $x$ and $p_n \to 0$. Think about the image of such an $f$:
$$\mathrm{im} f = f([0,p_n]) \ \forall n.$$
You should be able to finish by using continuity to deduce that $\mathrm{im} f = f(\{0\})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. what about my proof????

Comment: Your approach is a reasonable one to try, but it doesn't quite work yet. For fixed $y_k$ and $t_k$, you can't write any real number as $y_k + nt_k$. I'm not saying that it can't be fixed (perhaps by taking a sequence of $t_k$ and maybe of $y_k$), but the fix will be non-trivial. You'd have to prove you could write any real number in the way that you want. The reason that I didn't use that approach is that it didn't really exploit the full power of the hypotheses, namely regarding the range of a periodic function.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $f$ is periodic for any $a \in (0,\infty)$
$$f(x)=f(x+a)$$
for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We can see that $f(x)$ is differentiable and the derivative always yields
$$\lim_{b \to 0}\frac{f(x+b)-f(x)}{b}=\lim_{b \to 0}\frac{1}{b}\cdot 0=0$$
It follows that $f(x)$ is also infinitely differentiable. The Taylor series yields $f(x)=a_0,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ so $f(x)$ is just a constant function.

Comment: but Sir we did not study derivative yet